# Pass a PHP array to JavaScript for a horizontal on hover pop up submenu

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am currently working on a revamp of an outdated site. I have updated the html, php and converted it from a MySQL database to SQL database. All that is good and fine. My area of knowledge is in databases, PHP, SQL, and fair with the html. One problem is that the site is using an old JavaScript project/library called HM_LOADER.js which uses a hard coded array for the sub menu items HM_ARRAY.js. The function that creates main menu, and begins the use of the JavaScript is this:

```
function printOrderRequestOptions()
{
?>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2"
     SRC="HM_Loader.js"
     TYPE='text/javascript'></SCRIPT>
     
    <table width="142" height=450 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="500b4c">
    <tr>
       <td valign="middle">
       <a href="order.php" 
       onMouseOver="image1.src='/images/header/finance_on.gif';popUp('elMenu1',event)" 
       onMouseOut="image1.src='/images/header/finance_off.gif';popDown('elMenu1')">
       <img name="image1" src="/images/header/finance_off.gif" border=0></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td valign="middle">
       <a href="order.php" 
       onMouseOver="image2.src='/images/header/salesseries_on.gif';popUp('elMenu2',event)" 
       onMouseOut="image2.src='/images/header/salesseries_off.gif';popDown('elMenu2')">
       <img name="image2" src="/images/header/salesseries_off.gif" border=0></a>
       </td>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
       <td valign="middle">
       <a href="order.php" 
       onMouseOver="image3.src='/images/header/dealerservices_on.gif';popUp('elMenu3',event)" 
       onMouseOut="image3.src='/images/header/dealerservices_off.gif';popDown('elMenu3')">
       <img name="image3" src="/images/header/dealerservices_off.gif" border=0></a>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
  ?>
}
```

which in turn uses the hm_loader, that in turn uses the HM_array file that looks like this:

```
HM_Array1 = [ 
[150, 
142,  // left_position
145,  // top_position
],
["<b>Finance & Insurance</b>","/order_form.php?num=1&firstTime=1",1,0,0],
["<b>Legal Awareness</b>","/order_form.php?num=2&firstTime=1",1,0,0]
]

HM_Array2 = [
[180,
142, 
260,
],           
["<b>Sales Strength I</b>","/order_form.php?num=24&firstTime=1",1,0,0], 
["<b>Sales Strength II</b>","/order_form.php?num=25&firstTime=1",1,0,0],
//["<b>Sales Strength II Handouts</b>","/order_form.php?num=26&firstTime=1",1,0,0],
["<b>Communispond</b>","/order_form.php?num=36&firstTime=1",1,0,0],
["<b>PSS</b>","/order_form.php?num=35&firstTime=1",1,0,0]   
]   

HM_Array3 = [...
```

I need to make this dynamic based on queries from my database. Under my work guidelines I am allowed minimal restructuring of the site and files therein. So, basically they to keep the system intact as is, but make these sub menu items dynamic.

I know how to create my data structure in php and then JSON encode it, but how can I use that in this existing code system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but maybe this will get you started.

I suspect you are stuck somewhere between *getting the values from the database* and trying to *output them to javascript*. `json_encode()` is the answer here, you know that. I'm not sure where you are struggling exactly.

This will help with that, just throw it in an `example.php` and run it. It doesn't actually use the javascript, it just shows you the output (copy/paste to the console if you want to try it):

Here is a screenshot of the output: http://radleygh.com/images/chrome_2014-022-15-13-12-16.png

```
<?php
// Here is a single base object (HM_Array1), we'll add sub items separately
$array = array(
  'position' => array(
    150, // Mystery!
    142, // Left
    145, // Top
  ),
  'items' => array(),
);

// Add your items separately, preferably in a loop. This isn't a loop, that would be superflous.
$array['items'][] = array(
  'title' => '<b>Finance & Insurance</b>',
  'slug' => '/order_form.php?num=1&firstTime=1',
  'x' => 1,
  'y' => 0,
  'z' => 0,
);

$array['items'][] = array(
  'title' => '<b>Legal Awareness</b>',
  'slug' => '/order_form.php?num=2&firstTime=1',
  'x' => 1,
  'y' => 0,
  'z' => 0,
);

// You'll want to see how this works, so here's some debuggery:

echo '<h3>Preview of your object in PHP:</h3>';
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars( print_r($array, true) );
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr />';

echo '<h3>The javascript version:</h3>';
echo '<pre>';

ob_start();
?>
jQuery.parseJSON( '<?php echo json_encode( $array ); ?>' );
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
echo htmlspecialchars( print_r( $html, true) );

echo '</pre>';
```

The main part of this code is the `jQuery.parseJSON` line, which will produce an object version of the PHP array. You can then use that object to structure the `HM_ArrayN` arrays that you have provided using a function. Maybe you want to set this up with ajax, that's fine too, just parse the JSON after you perform the ajax query.

That javascript line of code will give you the following object:

```
Object {
  position: array(
    0: 150
    1: 142
    2: 145
  )

  items: array(
    0: {
      slug: "/order_form.php?num=1&firstTime=1"
      title: "<b>Finance & Insurance</b>"
      x: 1
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
    1: {
      slug: "/order_form.php?num=2&firstTime=1"
      title: "<b>Legal Awareness</b>"
      x: 1
      y: 0
      z: 0
    }
}
```

You can then build a function which converts this well-formed array into the format required by the specifications. Example below:

```
var myObject = (the javascript code above);
var HM_Array1 = new Array();

HM_Array1[0] = myObject.position[0];
HM_Array1[1] = myObject.position[1];
HM_Array1[2] = myObject.position[2];

for( i in myObject.items ) {
  var item = new Array();
  item[0] = myObject.items[i].title;
  item[1] = myObject.items[i].slug;
  item[2] = myObject.items[i].x;
  item[3] = myObject.items[i].y;
  item[4] = myObject.items[i].z;
  HM_Array.push( item );
}

console.log( HM_Array1 ); // Should look like your code.
```

Comment: Added a comment last night but I don't see it. Have been working on this since this morning. Will post the results and/or issues later. It is what I am looking to do, just trying to fit it into the current framework...

Comment: I know the advice you gave is good and I know I have been close a couple of times, but still its a no go. I am at 70+ hours on this one function. I rewrote 90% of a 12 year old site, converting from mysql to mssql and updating all the php/html (50+ image files and 120+ code files) in just over 160 hours. This popup menu is going to give me a stroke!

Comment: I could not get the json object to pass and produce the arrays I needed. I will post what I did in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the originating page, order.php I make to function calls 'getClass()' and then pass that to printOrderRequestOptions($mainMenu). they are simple functions that looks like this:

```
function getClass()
{
    $conn = connect();
    $SQL = "select order_form_class_id, order_form_class_desc from order_form_class where order_form_class_status_id='100'";

    $stmt = runsql($SQL, $res=NULL, $ERROR_MSG=NULL);
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $id = $row['order_form_class_id'];
        $desc= $row['order_form_class_desc'];
        $classIds[] = array($id , $desc);
    }
    return $classIds;
}
function printOrderRequestOptions($mainMenu)
{
?>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2"
         SRC="HM_Loader.js"
         TYPE='text/javascript'></SCRIPT>
     <style>
        a {text-decoration:none;}
     </style>

    <table width="142" height=450 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="500b4c">
    <tr><td><img name="image2" src="/images/header/generic_132X22.gif" border=0></a></td></tr>
    <?
        for ($i=0;$i<count($mainMenu);$i++)
        {
    ?>
        <tr>
           <td align="center" valign="middle">
           <a href="order.php" 
           onMouseOver="popUp('elMenu<?=$mainMenu[$i][0]?>',event)" 
           onMouseOut="popDown('elMenu<?=$mainMenu[$i][0]?>')">
           <font color="white"><b><? echo $mainMenu[$i][1]; ?></b></font>
           <img name="image<?=$i?>" src="/images/header/generic_132X22.gif" border=0></a>
           </td>
        </tr>
    <?
        }
    ?>
    </table>
<?
}
```

From here HM_LOADER.js is called, which sets and configs the params, and then looks to HM_Arrays.js for the actual data. The arrays file was list of hard coded arrays, and I needed them to be dynamic. This solution is not the best, but it is what I had to do to make this work since I was a week past my initial demo presentation. The HM_Arrays.js has been renamed HM_Arrays.php and now looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once("functions/functions.php");

$arrayCount = getClass();
$subItems = subMenuItems();
//for ($x=0;$x<count($arrayCount);x++)
//{
    $cnt = $arrayCount[0][0];
    //echo $arrayCount;
    print "HM_Array".$cnt." = [
    [150,
    142,  // left_position
    150,  // top_position
    ],";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($subItems);$i++)
    {
        if ($subItems[$i][0] == $cnt)
        print "['<b>".$subItems[$i][1]."</b>','/order_form.php?num=".$subItems[$i][2]."&firstTime=1',1,0,0],";
    }
    print "],";
//}


    $cnt = $arrayCount[1][0];
    print "HM_Array".$cnt." = [
    [325,
    142,  // left_position
    250,  // top_position
    ],";
    for ($i=0;$i<count($subItems);$i++)
    {
        if ($subItems[$i][0] == $cnt)
        print "['<b>".$subItems[$i][1]."</b>','/order_form.php?num=".$subItems[$i][2]."&firstTime=1',1,0,0],";
    }
    print "], ";


    $cnt = $arrayCount[2][0];
    print "HM_Array".$cnt." = [
    [195,
    142,
    350,
    ],";

    for ($i=0;$i<count($subItems);$i++)
    {
        if ($subItems[$i][0] == $cnt)
        print "['<b>".$subItems[$i][1]."</b>','/order_form.php?num=".$subItems[$i][2]."&firstTime=1',1,0,0],";
    }
    print "], ";


    $cnt = $arrayCount[3][0];
    print "HM_Array".$cnt." = [
    [240,   
    142,
    450,
    ],"; 
    for ($i=0;$i<count($subItems);$i++)
    {
        if ($subItems[$i][0] == $cnt)
        print "['<b>".$subItems[$i][1]."</b>','/order_form.php?num=".$subItems[$i][2]."&firstTime=1',1,0,0],";
    }
    print "] ";
?>
```

I know it is a bit ugly, but I could not get a for loop to work. I was using the count of getClass() for my counter, but it would not work. Each sub-menu became blank once I tried. This is a working solution, is there anyone who can help get this working with more efficient code??? Thanks for any and all help!